# emacs org mode agenda: in today's view do not show items with deadline for tomorrow

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

I have items that have a deadline for today and repeat daily, eg:

- TODO [#A] Exercise
  DEADLINE: <2020-09-08 Tue ++1d>

If this TODO has a deadline of today, that is great, I would like to see it in the agenda for today.

When I mark this TODO as done, and it then gets the deadline date to be tomorrow, it still shows up in the agenda for today prefaced by:

In  1 d.

And I dont want to see any items listed today that have a deadline for tomorrow.

Is there any way to set emacs org mode to do this?

I tried

(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'future)

But this does not work.

Thanks ahead of time....

Comment: Don't make it a DEADLINE? DEADLINE is for things that need to be done by a certain day, so Org mode specifically warns you about them ahead of time. For things, like "Exercise", you can use plain time stamps or habits.

Comment: Hey NickD, Thank you for your help! I am new to org mode and was inserting timestamps using the deadline command and was not aware I could just insert a timestamp without a deadline and make it recurring and it would still show up in agenda. So my question was a noon question but thank you for still being so helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to answer your question. It is possible to specify the lead time for warnings for each task as follows - the `-0d` says warnings should be zero days in advance:

```
DEADLINE: <2020-09-22 Tue +1d -0d>
```

This would allow you to do what I think your asking, without the heavy hammer of setting `org-deadline-warning-days` to 0.

Second, as several people mentioned, perhaps you want to schedule things for each day, not have a deadline for them each day.

Comment: Hey Jeffrey thanks for the help - I will try the lead time and I have removed the deadline from many items in my org mode file.

Answer (score 3):

see [8.3 Deadlines and Scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html)

> In addition, the agenda for today carries a warning about the approaching or missed deadline, starting org-deadline-warning-days before the due date

you can customize the variable `org-deadline-warning-days` to `0`to disable the prewarnings.

Comment: ... which defeats the purpose of deadlines, since it disables the warnings for *all* deadlines. That is why Org mode allows you different scheduling regimes: DEADLINE, SCHEDULED, or plain time stamps and [habits](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html#index-habits)- instead of twisting one beyong its breaking point, try to use the one that requires the least impedance matching (plain time stamps or habits in this case).